# Not getting the desired output with a Hive query

Tags: hive

I have two input files which are semicolon delimited. I loaded these files into two tables. Both tables contain the information on books. I joined both the tables on ISBN field. For creating these tables I used the below query to skip header and to read semi colon delimited files:-

```
Create table books (ISBN STRING,BookTitle STRING,BookAuthor STRING,YearOfPublication STRING,Publisher STRING,ImageURLS STRING,ImageURLM STRING,ImageURLL STRING) row format delimited fields terminated by '\;' lines terminated by '\n'  tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Now when I am trying the below query but I am not getting the desired output:-

```
SELECT a.BookRating, COUNT(BookTitle) 
FROM Books b 
JOIN Rating a 
on (b.ISBN = a.ISBN) 
WHERE b.YearOfPublication = 2002 
GROUP BY a.BookRating;
```

I am not getting anything. It just shows OK on the terminal after the query runs completely. Please let me know what can be done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL script is not proper.

You have mentioned

row format delimited fields terminated by '\;'

But actually it should be

**row format delimited fields terminated by ';'**

Try this and let me know

Comment: Hello Sunil, I tested the way you mentioned before but it is not working. I get an error if I do it this way. That is the reason I used '/;' . Please let me know if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

YearOfPublication is a string so you need to change it to

```
WHERE b.YearOfPublication = '2002'
```

Comment: Hi will try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hi I tried it but that also did not work. After running the query I just get OK and Time Taken and nothing else. Please suggest.